# Include Layout Over Top Scroll to AppBarLayout in Android

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I create Layout which consists 
    CoordinatorLayout
      AppBarLayout
       CollapsingToolbarLayout
        Image
        Toolbar

and include one layout for content.

Why the content layout when scroll up is over the toolbar?

This is pic first open Activity
   [This is pic first open Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPLzZ.png)
   [when scroll down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8nPU.png)
  [and scroll up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRTRL.png) 
main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".Activity_Movie">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

                <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                    app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/a_poster_joker" />

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

                </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

            <include layout="@layout/content_activity__movie" />

        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_activity__movie.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/Movie_Nested"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                tools:context=".Activity_Movie"
                tools:showIn="@layout/p__movie">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_margin="5dip"
                                android:orientation="vertical">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/Movie_Title"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:text="Title"
                                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                                    android:textSize="18sp"
                                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                            </LinearLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_margin="10dip"
                                android:orientation="horizontal">

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="160dip"
                                    android:layout_height="200dip"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                                    android:padding="5dip">

                                    <ImageView
                                        android:id="@+id/Movie_Img"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars[3]" />
                                </LinearLayout>

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="200dip"
                                    android:orientation="vertical"
                                    android:padding="10dip">

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:text="Score"
                                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                                    <LinearLayout
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:gravity="center"
                                        android:orientation="vertical">

                                        <com.mancj.slimchart.SlimChart
                                            android:id="@+id/slimChart"
                                            android:layout_width="80dip"
                                            android:layout_height="80dip"
                                            app:roundedEdges="true"
                                            app:strokeWidth="8dp"
                                            app:text="0"
                                            app:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />
                                    </LinearLayout>

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:text="Genre"
                                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/Movie_Genre"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:text="ACTION"
                                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:text="Release Date"
                                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/Movie_Release"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:text="2019-11-02"
                                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />
                                </LinearLayout>

                            </LinearLayout>

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_margin="10dip"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Sinopsis"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/Movie_Sinopsis"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text=". . . . . "
                                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:padding="5dip">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/Movie_Label_Other"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:text="Movie Action Lainnya"
                                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                            </LinearLayout>

                            <HorizontalScrollView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:animationCache="true"
                                android:elevation="4dp">

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:elevation="5dip"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                                    <GridView
                                        android:id="@+id/Movie_Grid"
                                        android:layout_width="1050dip"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                                        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                                        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
                                        android:columnWidth="100dip"
                                        android:elevation="5dip"
                                        android:gravity="center"
                                        android:horizontalSpacing="5dip"
                                        android:numColumns="10"
                                        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
                                        android:stretchMode="none"
                                        android:verticalSpacing="5dip" />
                                </LinearLayout>
                            </HorizontalScrollView>

                        </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this tag into toolbar :

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
```

hope it will help you.